# how to simulate json format and parse in ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I'm trying to simulate a json response by attaching it to a variable.

```
myjson =    {'link':{
      'href':'erwerweirwierwe',
      'rel':'self'
   },
   'plan':{
      'shortName':'Chrome',
      'shortKey':'MASTERFULL',
      'type':'chain',
      'enabled':true,
      'link':{
         'href':'something',
         'rel':'self'
      },
      'key':'MASTERFULL',
      'name':'teserere'
   }
```

when i try to parse the above, i get an error:

parsedJson = JSON.parse(myjson)

do i need to format the raw json before reading it this way?

Comment: It is difficult to tell whether you have a problem in Ruby or JSON, or both. It doesn't compile as Ruby. Could you add your error message to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use double quotes, not single quotes.

You can validate your json using [this web service](http://jsonlint.com/).

Also, in your example, you're missing the last closing brace.

The following JSON validates:

```
{
"link": {
    "href": "erwerweirwierwe",
    "rel": "self"
},
"plan": {
    "shortName": "Chrome",
    "shortKey": "MASTERFULL",
    "type": "chain",
    "enabled": true,
    "link": {
        "href": "something",
        "rel": "self"
    },
    "key": "MASTERFULL",
    "name": "teserere"
}
}
```